# Como puedo enviar multiples correos en PHP Mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

estoy utilizando la libreria PHP Mailer, para enviar correos, en este caso si los envía, pero únicamente a una sola dirección de correo, y yo quiero, por medio de un array que me traiga ciertos correos de la bd y los pueda enviar a cada uno de ellos. Este es el codigo de la libreria donde va el destinatario.

```
$mail->addAddress('yourusermail.com');
```

no puedo agregar por ejemplo:

```
    $mail->addAddress('yourusermail.com', 'meusermail@mail.com', 'theyuser@mail.com');
```

Answer (score 6):

Puedes repetir el método AddAddress tantas veces como necesites o bien usar la instrucción dentro de un ciclo:

```
  $mail->AddAddress('usuario1@dominiox.com');
  $mail->AddAddress('usuario2@dominioy.com');
  $mail->AddAddress('usuario3@dominioz.com');
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacer un for que se repita las veces de la longitud de tu arreglo:

```
$emails = array("yourusermail", "meusermail@mail.com", "theyuser@mail.com");

for($i = 0; $i < count($emails); $i++) {
    $mail->AddAddress($emails[$i]);
    echo $emails[$i];
}
```

Comment: Solo que en esta línea: `for($i = 0; $i < count($cars); $i++) {` la variable no sería `$cars` sino `$emails` para que cuente los elementos del array... o me equivoco?

Comment: Totalmente cierto, ya lo modifique, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Pero el envío de varios correos es una mala práctica no? Porque en la documentación de 'mailer' a lo último dice, Nota: no usar para mandar correos masivos porque abre sockets o algo así decía, yo también tengo esa duda, porque si tengo 1000 usuarios y quiero enviar un correo a cada uno de ellos estaría difícil ya que se podría colapsar la página